# Ubuntu 20.x - Get a list and path of all configuration files that have been modified by user and keep track of changes moving forward

Tags: backup, configuration, version-control

In light of a recent scare, I've decided that I don't want to have to redo all my configuration files in the event my OS crashes and I am forced to do a complete reinstall.

Assume someone has made substantial configuration modifications to obvious things like desktop, but also to other things like l2tp vpn configurations / esoteric bluetooth hacks etc..

Packages of course will be easy, but what about other stuff?

My question is:  What's the easiest way to find configuration files that have been changed, copy them along with folder path and then keep up to date with future changes?

I'm assuming I could start int /etc and look for files that have been modified after the OS install date.

Regarding tracking changes moving forward - my first thought was using git locally on another computer?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm actually interested in what answers you get. But two things - not just /etc as files often get modified in /var and /opt as well. And how to differentiate from configs vs random stuff..eg if you install a package, it's effectively new/modified file but also, if you use the out-of-the-box config that came with package, no need to keep it backed up. But, again, I'd like to see what people use for cases like this. And yes, agree, git would be good destination for tracking changes. Just keep the repo secure (all kinds of things are in those configs). But I feel like it will be a manual setup

Comment: I will try N0rbert's suggestions later and report back with a comment and accepted answer (I assume they will work fine) - the suggestions sound fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try:

- [etckeeper](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/etckeeper) for version control of `/etc`;
- [debsums](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/debsums) to check the changes in `/etc` with `sudo debsums --config --changed --silent`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  Regarding etckeeper, which have had to best success with? (git, mercurial, bzr or darcs)

Comment: Currently Git is a production standard.

Comment: A dpkg command that dovetails debsums quite well is this -> dpkg -S /pathtofile/filename
An example:
root@mycomputer:/home/user# dpkg -S /etc/ipsec.secrets 
strongswan-starter: /etc/ipsec.secrets